# Jquery script doesn't work in jquery loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to search for similar questions, but I could not find anything, so if you know any similar question please let me know.

Let me explain what Im doing:
I have a script that validates forms in a js file, It works fine in any page with a form I have, the problem is that when I load a form using jquery it just doesn't work, I have tried using the next line in different places: Header, footer, etc

```
<script src='myFile.js'></script>
```

By far the only thing that has worked for is writing the line of code above inside the form itself.
I think it has something to do with the form that the DOM works, I have also tried using and not using it.

```
$(document).ready(function (){ //code});
```

It only will work when I add the script tag with the src attribute inside the form itself.

It would not represent a big problem for me to add the script tag to any form I load using jquery but it's a little bit more of work an unefficient, and also when I add the script tag to any form and load it using ajax I get the next console warning that only goes away when I remove the script tag from the form file:

jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Here is a part of my code:

```
<!--home.html-->
<div id='formFrame'>
</div>

<script>

    $("#formFrame").load("html/loginForm.html");

</script>
<!--end of home.html-->

<!--loginForm.html-->
<form action='somePage.php' method='post' id='loginForm'>
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='email'>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
</form>
<script src='js/validate.js'></script>
<!--end of loginForm.html-->

<!--validation script (validate.js)-->
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#loginForm").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Working");
    });
});
```

Thanks for spending some of your valuable time on reading this, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: you need to put $(document).ready in script tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nair, $(document).ready is already written in my script tag (validate.js), I think I could be missunderstanding you, Could you please indicate me exactly where to put it?

Comment: `$("#formFrame").load("html/loginForm.html");` I think you are trying to load on an element that doesnt exist yet. you could use the .ready() but why not put the .load() line in the same block as the ready() you already have?

Comment: you need to put the scripts in correct order . If you need to call a function in jquery you need to load jquery first

Comment: Hery Jason thanks, I tried but I had no luck, I tried adding $(document).ready in the line you wrote abobe but that won't work, Also tried doing that same thing and removing the ready statement in the script file but that doesn't work too and that causes other element not to function anymore, I think the answer would have more to do with logic than with syntax, because as I previously said the script works well, the problem is when I try to use the script on a form loaded using ajax. I really appreciate the help all of you have provided to me. Thanks I hope we can solve this asap :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys I found a solution:

As there seems to be a conflict when loading an external page using ajax (.load) I opted to use php instead of javascript which worked fine:

I removed the next code

```
<script>

    $("#formFrame").load("html/loginForm.html");

</script>
```

And added the next to the div where I want to load my content:

```
<!--home.php (changed html to php)-->
<div id='formFrame'>
    <?php
        require 'html/loginForm.html';
    ?>
</div>
```

I would have prefered to use the load method from ajax to avoid loading the content befere the user could request it, but by far that's the only solution I have been able to think about.
Thanks to everybody for your help it was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment, putting my comment in answer!

I am not sure what you have written in validate.js, but if you are using jQuery unobtrusive validation, then you must rebind the validators to the form if you are loading it dynamically.

I was facing same issue in ASP.NET MVC while loading forms using AJAX. I am not sure will it help you or not but below is the code.

```
 $("#formFrame").load("html/loginForm.html", function(){
    var $form = $("formSelector");
    $form.removeData('validator');
    $form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unluckily Im not using jQuery unobtrusive validation or any plugin, all Im using is jquery :(, Im thinking about a possible solution if it works I'll answer my own question. Thanks anyway man!

Comment: Oh! Hope your possible solution will work! Meanwhile will be good if you can also put some code from your validate.js in the question! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for yor desires, I added an aswer that worked for me, thanks for your time man!